# html table with radio button copy paste into xls

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have an HTML `table` element, with rows containing not only plain-text characters, but also `radio buttons`, `lists`, etc.

What I would like to have, is when the user copy-pastes the content of the table into MS Excel (as plain text), the `radio buttons` should be replaced with their values (e.g.: "checked", and "unchecked"), lists elements should be replaced by their selected value, etc.

Is there a way to implement this in the browser? 
(Preferably without using flash or java applet components)

Thanks,
krisy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use javascript (this will be easier with a framework like jquery) to modify the code that has been copied. The general procedure would be to set the radio buttons to be invisible and then add in text in their place based on their current value.

There are plenty of questions to help with the implementation details: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+copied+text&submit=search

**Update:** Turns out you don't even need to remove the radio buttons, at least for my version of excel. Here is a working example (way over-commented to explain what's going on):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type='text/css'>
      .radioCopyVal{
      font-size: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='radio' name='woots' id='oneWoot' checked/><span class='radioCopyVal'>Checked.</span></td>
      <td><label for='oneWoot'>Woot.</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='radio' name='woots' id='twoWoot' /><span class='radioCopyVal'>Not checked.</span></td>
      <td><label for='twoWoot'>Woot. Woot.</label></td>
    </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      $("#oneWoot").attr("checked", true); //on page load, make sure oneWoot is the default selection

      $("input[name=woots]:radio").change(function(){ //anytime the radio buttons of name woots are changed...
          $(".radioCopyVal").remove(); //remove the old radioCopyVal spans (to be replaced with new ones)
          $("input[name=woots]:radio").each(function() { //for each radio button in name woots
              if ($(this).attr("checked")) { //if the button is checked, add a span saying 'Checked.' after it. css is used to hide the span
                  $(this).after('<span class="radioCopyVal">Checked.</span>');
          }else {
              $(this).after('<span class="radioCopyVal">Not checked.</span>');
          }
          })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds nice; I was thinking about creating a 1px*1px text area, and capturing the CTRL key and the onMouseDown element; when the even occurs, the selected text will be processed (radio button, etc replace with their values), the processed text will be written to the text area, selected, and the focus will be direct to that area. This way it might be possible, to achive the desired functionallity (?)

Comment: Luckily, it's easier than that. I added an example to my original answer.

Comment: Works fantastic, thanks! When copy-pasting into excel, choosing the Paste special/Text option, everything is ok. I think I will need to get this work without using Paste special. (currently the chekboxes are also copied into the xls with their "checked" String as well)

Answer (score 1):

Not possible I'm afraid. But you could do like this:
Have a link that leads to a javascript and the script will hide these items and show their values in plain text so this operation can be reversed.

This can be easily done using JQuery:
This shows the radio value:

```
$("input:radio").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        $(this).after('<span class="value">checked</span>');
    }
    else {
        $(this).after('<span class="value">unchecked</span>');
    }
}).css("display", "none");
```

I left a span class so that these values then can be hided easily using script.